# Applet NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm having trouble uploading Java applets to my website.
I am new to making applets so I have never done this before but I am not new to Java.
I want to know if there is a problem is in my code or if it is something else. The file I'm adding to my website is a class file that was in the bin file of my project.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class arcade2 extends JApplet
{
   public void paint (Graphics g)
   {
      g.drawString ("Hello World", 25, 50);
   }
}
```

And here is my website code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="arcade2.class" width="600" height="800"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you find something wrong? If not it is probably a problem with my hosting. The error that appears is `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: 1) Did it never occur to you to show the location of the class file & HTML?  (Do you think the JRE loads the class using magic?)  It would also help if you provided the link where we can see the HTML. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.

Comment: Since you seem to have abandoned this question, I am voting to close.

Comment: I think you should give him his weekend ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, do the following:

1. Put your class into a jar file, e.g. Applet.jar
2. put that jar file next to your html file
3. Adapt your html file to: `<applet archive="Applet.jar" code="arcade2.class" width="600" height="800"></applet>`
4. double klick your html file

I think due to the recent changes in applet security it still won't work, so you have to sign your applet. For testing purposes go to the java control panel, tab 'Security' and lower the bar to 'middle' then your are able to execute it.

And one last thing, in Java class files are starting with big letters, so you should call it Arcade2.java

Comment: YES! archive worked. But I don't think I need a jar unless I'm using multiple classes.

Comment: I am not quite sure whether this works anymore with the new 'Next Generation Plugin'. E.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html doesn't mention that...

Comment: And if you look in the table for the jnlp file you see that it is required to specify a jar file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html#resources